# Laptop doesn't suspend when lid is closed

Tags: power-management

I have LTS Ubuntu 12.04 and when I close my lid  the screen goes black but doesn't suspend because I can feel it getting warmer as if it was processing something. When I open it back up after an hour, I can see that all my battery is drained.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

I had the same problem listed here. When the laptop lid closed, the screen turned black and the fan was still on and didn't resume when I opened the lid. After I installed this package, it suspended correctly and resumed when I opened it.

Comment: My laptop used to instantly resume from suspend (no matter if lid closed or manually set to sleep). After installing laptop-mode-tools it's working as it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Power . From there you can change this. I'm attaching a photo about it. [image: Power Settings]

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.